# Which container should I use in WPF to draw geometric shapes with correct positioning?

Tags: wpf, layout, shapes

I want to use Shapes in WPF to display some mathematically defined objects (dots, polylines, reference axes) in a way that is similar to a geometric chart or plot. I want to use Shapes because of their interactivity, since the user is supposed to click over them, highlight them with mouseover, etc.

The Shape objects themselves are to be databound to their geometric definitions in the ViewModel. I can choose the type of each property according to what would me most convenient (PointCollection, PathFigure, Point, etc.).

Problem is: so far, I am trying with Canvas container, which has some particular layout characteristics which make it hard for me to get it right. Specifically, it has its origin on top-left, so my shapes appear upside down unless I use RenderTransform (which I do not oppose to do);

Besides that, I have a BoundingBox property in ViewModel (of type `Rect`) which should be used to "fit" or "autozoom" inside the control, but since model coordinates are not screen coordinates, I would have to apply some Transform.

Unfortunately, I can only apply Transforms to Geometries, and I can do so using an Image with DrawingImage as source, with GeometryDrawings describing the shapes. But then I lose all the required characteristics of Shapes in the first place (styling and interaction mostly).

And that's why I am stuck, so my question boils down to:

"How can I transform the geometry of shapes so that they are correctly positioned inside of a 'reference viewport' in a Canvas?"

Here is some unsatisfactory code, with the Image control displaying the desired layout:

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DrawingGraficos"
    x:Class="DrawingGraficos.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="204.333" Height="181">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:DesenhoViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TranslacaoConverter x:Key="TranslacaoConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <UniformGrid Rows="0" Columns="2">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvasviewport">
            <Polygon Points="{Binding BoundingBoxCorners}" Fill="LightGray"/>
            <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Data="{Binding GeometriaLinhaSimetria}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Image>
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" CenterY=".5"/>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
            <Image.Source>
                <DrawingImage>
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding Limites}"/>
                            </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="LightGray">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding Limites}"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="{Binding GeometriaLinhaSimetria}">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="2"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </UniformGrid>

</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Miotec.MVVM;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace DrawingGraficos
{
    public class DesenhoViewModel : ViewModelBase {

        public Rect Limites {
            get {
                double largura = 70;
                double altura = 100;
                return new Rect(new Point(-largura*0.5,-30), new Point(largura*0.5,altura-30));
            }
        }

        public PointCollection BoundingBoxCorners {
            get {
                return new PointCollection() {
                    Limites.BottomLeft, Limites.TopLeft, Limites.TopRight, Limites.BottomRight
                };
            }
        }

        public Point Origem { get { return new Point(0,0); } }

        public List<Point> LinhaSimetria {
            get {
                return new List<Point> {
                    new Point(-3,-20),
                    new Point(0,-15),
                    new Point(2,-10),
                    new Point(4,-5),
                    new Point(4,0),
                    new Point(2,5),
                    new Point(2,10),
                    new Point(0,15),
                    new Point(-2,20),
                    new Point(-2,25),
                    new Point(-2,30),
                    new Point(-2,35)
                };
            }
        }

        public Geometry GeometriaLinhaSimetria {
            get {
                var sb = new StringBuilder("M");
                foreach (var p in LinhaSimetria) {
                    sb.AppendFormat(" {0};{1}", p.X, p.Y);
                }
                string result = sb.ToString().Replace(",",".").Replace(";",",");
                return Geometry.Parse(result);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Look into the `ViewBox` control. You can put pretty much anything inside it (like your canvas) and it will automatically scale it all for you. Then you could probably apply a transform to flip the `ViewBox` upside down.

Comment: @Steve yeah, that is one approach, BUT (sorry I didn't mention it before) two things that cannot happen are: StrokeThickness should not scale (which would happen inside Viewbox) and Text should not be displayed upside down (which happens with Layout or Render Transform).

Comment: You can fix the StrokeThickness by scaling it based on the zoom of the Viewbox, and the text can be rotated so they show up in the right orientation. I've had to do this and it sucks tho.